# Redirect conflicting with RewriteRule, what may be causing it?

Tags: .htaccess

I am currently switching from olddomain.com into newdomain.com and at the top of my `.htaccess` I have the following `Redirect`'s:

```
Redirect 301 /pageA/ http://newsite.com/pageA
Redirect 301 /pageB/ http://newsite.com/pageB
Redirect 301 /pageCa/ http://newsite.com/pageCb
Redirect 301 /pageD/ http://newsite.com/pageD
```

As you can see there, one of the redirects, "pageCa" changes to "pageCb" and sometimes the 301's take precedence. If I later type the same URL it acts as if the 301's aren't there and the below catch all takes effect instead.

```
# Catch all for pages different from the Redirects
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.oldsite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newsite.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

- **What may be causing this conflict?**

Both domains are under the same `DocumentRoot` and everything else seems to work reliably.

My full `.htaccess`:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54s .php

Redirect 301 /pageA/ http://newsite.com/pageA
Redirect 301 /pageB/ http://newsite.com/pageB
Redirect 301 /pageCa/ http://newsite.com/pageCb
Redirect 301 /pageD/ http://newsite.com/pageD

ErrorDocument 404 /404

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

# Removes www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Catch all for pages different from the Redirects
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.oldsite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newsite.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Maps to php files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]

# All 404 requests
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/404$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newsite.com/404 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Prix. Sorry, the code references oldsite.com and newsite.com where the urls are changing.  
An example of a page name change is where I reference "pageCa" and "pageCb".  
Sometimes the 301s take precedence, if I later type the same url it acts as if the 301s aren't there and the catch all takes effect.  
Any more specific questions?

Comment: The sites do share the same DocumentRoot. Yes this has been the only issue, everything else seems to work reliably. Thanks for the note on the 404.

Comment: Does it happens if you convert it into `RewriteCond`/`RewriteRule` pairs and place it right before the `# Catch all for pages different from the Redirects`? I've also updated your question to reflect the updates you gave on the comments, if I perhaps removed or change the meaning of something, kindly edit to your needs.

Comment: I added an answer which is working, any comments on why the redirects weren't? Is there a precedence to the rules in htaccess files?

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seems to be working with the following before the "catch all" instead of the redirects:

Where the page name stays the same, url changing:

```
RewriteRule ^oldsite.com/pageA/?$ http://newsite.com/pageA [L]
```

Where both are different:

```
RewriteRule ^pageCa/?$ http://newsite.com/pageCb [L]
```

Thanks